# adal angular app reloading - by design?

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, adal

I have built a simple angular app and for authentication, I authenticate against AzureAD using use the npm package `adal-angular4`

When authentication happens, the user gets sent to `https://login.microsoftonline.com` they login and get sent back to the agulare app which causes a reload/recompile which will cause a load time delay, only short but the overall load time experience is doubled.

[image: network view]

As you can see above :

- login is loaded (localhost)
- app is compiled
- user taken to login screen (azuread)
- user logs in and user is taken back to login (localhost)
- app is complied

The load gap between `main.bundle.js` and `background'` is a simple way to show the compile time, its only a VERY TIME but I have a VERY FAST PC.

**What can be done to avoid the recompile? My thoughts are**

- Do all the auth in the index.html (eg, pre first load of APP) and just save the JWT token to the session storage
- Find an angular packages do this via an IFRAME

Anyone got any thoughts on this? maybe `adal-angular4` should use an IFRAME?

**Some more details**

[Example](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4-example%20example) of `adal-angular4`

Microsofts anglurejs [example](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/samples/JwtBearerSample) which uses this [javascrit](https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.0/js/adal.js%20this) maybe this is a good starting place for a pure JavaScript solutoon thats executed from the index.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use adal.js directly not via the angular application.

In the main index.html add the following code

```
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.0/js/adal.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.config = {
  instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
  tenant: 'yourtenant.co.uk',
  clientId: '11111111-1111-1111-1111-1111111111',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
};
// Check For & Handle Redirect From AAD After Login
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
authContext.handleWindowCallback();
if (isCallback && !authContext.getLoginError()) {
    window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
}
var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
if (!user) {
  authContext.login();
}
</script>
```

The index.html can still load all the javascript for the angular app, the above code will execute.

Within my angular app I use `angular2-jwt` which expects the token to be in `token` so I needed to move the token with the following code :

```
localStorage.setItem('token', localStorage.getItem( 'adal.access.token.key' + config.clientId));
```

I added a message in the app `AppComponent` you can see this in the debug console.

Old way, you can see the re-load.. 
[image]
Pure JavaScript way, as you see, just one app load. 
[image]

Comment: Did that help avoid reload/recompile the app multiple times?

Comment: yep, index.html loads, i don't even see the loading or any sign of the angular app. It then takes me to azure ad auth and takes me back to my app which then loads. If I am already logged in I don't see the Azure UI I just see the network traces in the debug tools.

Comment: I have added a clip, the clip does not really show the slow down which is very short on my i7 desktop, it's more apparent on slower kit.

Comment: Looks really fast! Nice work.

I now face another problem. I'm trying the `endpoints` property because I need to get some other tokes as well, eg Graph. The problem is that for each resource in that array I get an `iFrame` injected into the page, which again causes the app to reload/recompile multiple times. The initial load feels very slow even if the app is just a barebone hello world. Have you tried that? Do you think your approach will work for that case?

Comment: not tried yet, this is my first real play with `adal.js` .

Comment: That was probably a long shot but thanks :) And good luck with `adal.js`.

Comment: @DzhavatUshev, I have just added some code to refresh the token, and I see what you mean. It creates an IFRAME that sends a request to `login.microsoftonline.com` and then that sends a 302 to redirect to YOUR homepage which is going tobe index.html. I guess you could detect if you are within an IFRAME and if you are don't bootstrap Angular or get it to redirect to a static HTML? It just needs to set some state. I may log a bug on git see if that helps.

Comment: add `redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/frameRedirect.html'` create the page and let it handle the call backs, this works for the token refresh.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your advises. I'm going to try them out and see if that will help.

Comment: Steve Drake, are there more steps in the /frameRedirect approach? I changed the redirectUri but get a 'sorry, we're having trouble signing you in' page. Maybe a setting on AAD? Thanks

Comment: Hello, I did get it all working and I am happy with the result. I had todo some exception handling within the Angular App when the token expired (had a sort of race condition) and I had todo a little work for the refresh of the token. Its not gone into prod YET. I will try to get the code uploaded to pastebin or something.

Comment: but yes, more work, the code above in the index.html is a good start. I may even blog it, busy with other work commitments right now but I will try my best.

Comment: Thanks Steve, if I use what you have in your index.html, for making Api calls within the angular app - do I remove all the

    import { Adal4HTTPService } from 'adal-angular4'; stuff and manually build the auth headers with angular2-jwt? My issue with adal-angular 4 is it reloads the app on every api call so if something calls the api on load I get  infinite reload hell!

Comment: I removed ALL AUTH code from Angular, I let the Index.html page do all the work. All I do in angular is parse the JWT token and if it's expired or missing I take them to a page that basically says you need to login.

Comment: Nice - look forward to seeing your example

Comment: Hi Steve - your index.html example works great, I also use this page to aqcuireToken for our API then read this from localStorage in angular  - I was wondering how you deal with the expiry? use jwt to check validity then a location.href to the main page again? Thank you

Comment: I let the index html page check for expiration, sometimes when you return to your app the token refresh does not happen in time and the jwt parse fails. I could try to make the app wait, but I just treat this as a corner case and take the user to a please wait logging in page that resets all the date and starts over.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, this is not able to avoid. When the app interact with Azure AD via the Oauth protocol, the flow is like below:

1. users click start login-in progress from app
2. the app was redirected to the identity data provider(Azure AD)
3. users enter the username/password
4. the identity data provider response with the 302 redirection to the app

> Do all the auth in the index.html (eg, pre first load of APP) and just save the JWT token to the session storage

No, as see the progress in the steps above the authentication has two steps. First is authentication with Azure AD, then the web app authenticate the users with the id_token issued by Azure AD.

More detail about the Oauth 2.0, you can refer the link below:

[The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

Comment: with the JWT slant, the JavaScript code generates the JWT token and its stored in the browsers session store. When we issue requests to the backend, the backend (using the standard JWT bits from .net) knows who the user is and knows his/her roles as they are all part of the JWT token. The token is verified by using the issuer property. This all works fine.. The issue is that the JavaScipt that does all this is loaded into the SinglePageApp so we have to wait for it to load, if we did this work via javascript in the html page that loads the SPA it will prevent the double load.

Comment: the AzureAD does send a 302, but if  you look its all client side params, eg after the # the `adal-angular4` lib will parse this and turn it into a JWT token.  `Location: http://localhost:4200/login#id_token=SNIP&state=870268a2-2009-4e1c-99fd-262bbcc3ec77&session_state=ccc2a466-8c50-45f9-a83e-104919b057e5` the token that I have SNIPPED is just the JWT token, nothing very complex.

Comment: @SteveDrake If the 'app complied' means app reloading, this is not be able to avoid. The root cause for this is that the URL is changed in the browser when authenticate using OAuth flow. So that the HTML document have to reload. It doesn't matter which library you were developing.

Comment: yes, but its the time it takes for the angular app to load that is the issue, I am going to try doing that auth redirects from `index.html` before the angular app has even started to load. I will re-post when I do this. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If you look at some MS sites, such as teams.microsoft.com you can see that the auth is done before the 'loading' screen displayed. The issue is the `adal-angular4` code is loading while the 'loading' screen is being displayed. Moving the auth before the loading screen does make sence.

Comment: @fei-xue-msft , I have moved the auth into the main index.html and it works very well. Thanks for you input